# How to get application usage time?

Tags: c#, windows, desktop-application

I need to get all the other applications usage time. I can get which window is active now using GetForegroundWindow. But how can I get notified when the window goes inactive. We cant check repeatedly whether the window is active or not. I dont need the ( process start time - current time) which gives how long the process is running. I want how long the window is active.

Comment: Do you use wpf or windows forms? Do you build an application to control the usage time of other applications? Is that right.

Comment: I am using wpf. yes, my application needs the usage time of other windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into [`SetWindowsHookEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx), and specifically, [`WH_CBT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Do you have any sample code? I could not able to understand the function properly.

Comment: yeah ! I got some among those tons of examples. Thanks !